# Can we create command line users to freeradius?

Tags: freeradius

I search an solution to creating users in command line, and to implement a script.
I'm starting in IT i need help please.
Sry to my bad language i'm french

Comment: I think you better google it, and this question is related to another stack site I think .. maybe something like https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I keep searching on google